# how to implement random pooling in tensorflow that takes random pixel in each sliding window

Tags: python, tensorflow

tensorflow's [tf.nn.pool](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/pool)
either takes average or maximum pixel in each nhood/window

I want to implement random pooling, that is to take a random pixel in each window

when applied of kernel/window/nhood size of 3x3 on this input

`| a b c A B C |
| d e f D E F |
| g h i G H I |`

would result a random lower case letter and a random upper case letter

`| gC |`

a second run might give

`| eA |`

Answer (score 1):

Your question and your example are actually not expressing the same problem. Let me assume that your example reflects your need: you want to split your input into non-overlapping tiles, and extract a random sample out of each of them.

In that case, you use `tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax` on a surrogate random image the same size as your input.

```
my_input = ... # for example a 1x3x6x1 tensor similar to your example
tile_size = [1, 3, 3, 1]
r = tf.random_uniform(my_input.shape)
maxr, idxs = tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(r, tile_size, tile_size, 'SAME')
rand_samp_per_tile = tf.reshape(tf.gather(tf.reshape(my_input, [-1]), idxs), maxr.shape)
```

A *real* random pooling over overlapping sliding windows cannot rely on this trick, and you would need to basically do the random sampling yourself. This would be more demanding, mostly because you would have to handle yourself the offsets of the sliding windows, depending on the tensor size, the window size, and the padding type.

Comment: actually I want the second option. a real random pooling on possibly overlapping sliding window

Comment: @muayyadalsadi then it's possible but that's more work as explained above. Unless somebody has already implemented a similar function, I think it is unlikely somebody will do it here for you.

Comment: I've done a simple solution, but I want to make it perfect then I'll share it

Answer (score 0):

I've created a function styled after `tf.nn.max_pool` and `tf.layers.max_pooling2d`
you can find the full version in my [github gist](https://gist.github.com/muayyad-alsadi/39506bdf906568fcdeb7b1a8f6aeba36)

I've created a constant tensor holding corner points of each polling window, then another tensor holding two random offsets (along height and one along width) from each window corner using `tf.random_uniform`

`tr = tf.random_uniform((N, ch, cw, 2), 0, k, tf.int32)`

the offset should be the same along color channels, for this I used `tf.stack` and `tf.transpose`

finally I used `tf.gather_nd` to pick pixels and form final tensor

```
N, H, W, C = inputs.shape
CH, CW =  (H, W) if padding==PADDING_SAME else (H-k+1, W-k+1)
# corner points
c = np.array([ [ [ [ (i, h, w, j) for j in range(C) ] for w in range(0, CW, s) ] for h in range(0, CH, s) ] for i in range(N)])
ch, cw = c.shape[1], c.shape[2]
tc = tf.constant(c, dtype=tf.int32)
# random offset from corner, same shape as center point, contains redundant axis for C
tr = tf.random_uniform((N, ch, cw, 2), 0, k, tf.int32)
# repeat each C times, and make [y, x] into [0, y, x, 0]
tr = tf.transpose(tf.stack([tr for i in range(C)]), [1, 2, 3, 0, 4])
tr = tf.pad(tr, [[0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [ 1, 1 ]])
# index of randomly shifted center point
if padding==PADDING_VALID:
    ix = tc+tr
else:
    # max points
    m = np.array([ [ [ [ (N-1, H-1, W-1, C-1) for j in range(C) ] for w in range(0, CW, s) ] for h in range(0, CH, s) ] for i in range(N)])
    tm = tf.constant(m, dtype=tf.int32)
    ix = tf.minimum(tc+tr, tm)
return tf.gather_nd(inputs, ix, name=name)
```